# In Hibernate; is there a way to update top level "updatedDate" column if any child row gets updated?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistent

I have a table that stores an ID field that is used to link many other child objects in hibernate.

The child tables all have a generated column called "Parent_ID" or something similar. The top level object also has some general fields such as createdBy, updatedBy, createdDate and updatedDate.

At the moment when a child object gets updated there are no trigger to update the parent "Updated###" fields. I want one field that stores info on any child updates. Is this possible? I've tried a few different ways as well as reading the docs. I am new to hibernate so if this breaks some fundamental please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you mark that column as `@Version` and then the association within which the child object is contained with `Cascade.ALL`, the version will be "incremented" automatically when you call `EntityManager.merge` on the parent entity.